# background url не работает правильно

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

```
var image_url = data.productList[i].productImageFilePath;
item_div_productImage.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image_url +')';
item_div_productImage.style.visibility = "visible";
```

image_url получаю из json но при загрузке к данному пути в начале прибавляется путь самого html файла

```
http://localhost:63342/lad/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/media.gettyimages.com/photos/colorful-powder-explosion-picture-id550582551
```

Comment: какой у вас урл относительный?

Comment: Какая ссылка в view-source? Браузер из "относительной" ссылки делает "прямую" она может хорошо отличатся.

Comment: Почему в картинке нету расширения? Ваш сайт - может случайно стать прекрасной средой для вирусов? Надо запрещать вообще без расширения фалы обрабатывать.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляй к ссылке http/https префикс

было:

```
media.gettyimages.com/photos/colorful-powder-explosion-picture-id550582551
```

стало:

```
http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/colorful-powder-explosion-picture-id550582551
```

Comment: ещё вариант /photos/colorful-powder-explosion-picture-id550582551 что б не зависеть от домена. Ссылки лучше давать относительные, что б код был переносимый. А что если тестовый сервак дадут. Или у себя на компе потестить сайт? Менять ссылки?